# Is there any better option that PI4J to write/read from UART in raspbian?

Tags: raspberry-pi, serial-port, uart, wiringpi, pi4j

i'm looking for a better way for UART I/O in my raspberryPI in the linux side where i'm using Java.
now i'm using PI4J (wiringPI) but i'm facing few problems, i noticed many missing messages. 
Also it's limited to 57600 baud rate and i wish to use higher. 
So i was wondering if there is another well tested way to communicate.

In the other side i run c on cc2530 which run perfectly. 
My main problem is in the java side where some messages get lost. 
Thanks

Comment: To communicate with what, exactly?  Be specific.

Comment: I'm communicating with a cc2530 TI chip via UART

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the exact Zigbee module you're working with, but [this summary](http://www.ti.com/product/CC2530) of the CC2530 says that it supports UART and SPI.  Perhaps you can check the documentation for the module you're using and see if SPI might be a better alternative. Depending on the 2530's capability, SPI can be much faster than 57600.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i edited my question adding some details. my problem is in the linux side where i run Java, not in the zigbee module

Answer (score 0):

Ok Found the JSerialComm which give what i needed.